# Какие критерии остановки деления Octree?

Tags: алгоритм

Использую octree для ускорения рейтрейсинга и столкнулся с проблемой: как понять до какого момента нужно делить octree? Знаю, что можно по глубине и кол-ве объектов в октанте, но как мне рассчитать эти минимальные значения я не знаю?

Comment: Измерьте влияние количества объектов в нижних октантах на скорость рендеринга. Выберите лучший вариант.

Comment: Глубину задавать равной по всему дереву - неправильно. Где-то пусто, где-то густо. Ограничить сверху можно.